# Array for map function in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to use `map` for an `array` like this one. I cannot predict the name, and there is no common key - just name value pairs, which can be different

`{"name":"Text","description":"Text","some other item":"Text"}`

I tried various approaches, but most of them require some kind of identifier. It would be great to understand how this can be solved.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Object` conversion :

```
Object.values(values).map(e => console.log(e)); //to get a map of the values
Object.keys(values).map(e => console.log(e)); //to get a map of the keys
Object.entries(values).map(e => console.log(e)); //to get a map of [key, value]
```

You can check theses Object mapping [with a live demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-fire-sx6he) and [a documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) like this:

```js
const obj = {"name":"Text","description":"Text","some other item":"Text"}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  console.log(`key: ${key}`)
  console.log(`value: ${obj[key]}`)
})
```